# How to calculate interrupt latency in Ubuntu programmatically?

Tags: operating-system, pthreads, interrupt, latency, interrupt-handling

Interrupt latency is defined as the time between when an interrupt occurs and when the first instruction of Interrupt service routine (ISR) starts to process the interrupt. To calculate the interrupt latency I was following the method mentioned in this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8441042

Basically I was thinking to create a thread (at time-point t1) using pthread library in C, then wait for 100 microseconds and generate an interrupt (at time-point t2). Then the interrupt latency time would be t2-t1-100 microseconds. But I am unable to get how to actually generate such an interrupt and how to measure time-point t2 just at the beginning of such an interrupt?

OR if there is some other better way to calculate interrupt latency programmatically, please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Ugh......maybe with a driver that does not clear the interrupt so that it is 'immediately' re-invoked upon IRET for some large count?  Timing data for interrupt ack/return might then allow you to calculate an average guess at int ack time.  TBH, if I was asked to try this, I might well respond by an update-CV cycle.   Very unsure about your plan - 100us is forever in processor cycles.

Comment: Is it possible to estimate the interrupt latency by just writing some C code? So that whoever wants to reproduce the results can just compile and run the C code on their system.

Comment: I would say no.  With installing a driver, maybe, barely, possible. Interrupt acknowledge cycles are hardware operations and, individually, imp....very difficult to meter with software alone.

Comment: Why do you need to find this out?

Comment: Just as an academic exercise. I was trying to measure different things like context switch time, semaphore shuffling time etc which I learnt in my OS class. I was looking for something like this blog: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/measuring-context-switching-and-memory-overheads-for-linux-threads/ . In this they calculate context switch time using pipes and conditional variables. So I was wondering whether we could approximate latency in a similar fashion.

Comment: Ok, I looked at the site and found 'The first thing that happens during a context switch is a switch to kernel mode, either through an explicit system call (such as write to some file or pipe) or a timer interrupt'.  That is incomplete and misleading - it ignores the absolutely vital and basic I/O completion interrupts.  I didn't read any further since the author is so incompetent.

Comment: ..and interrupt latency is only a tiny contribution to thread context switch timing.  Compared with running the scheduler state machine and dispatching threads onto cores, is insignificant.

Comment: In.order to assist you, I suggest that you ignore all 'intro to threads' books/sites that mention timer interrupts before I/O completions.  Other touchstones of crap are words/phrases like 'timer-scheduled', 'quantum' and 'give up the remainder of their time-slice'.  It's all cargo-cult copypasta that is grossly misleading:(

Comment: If you are really interested in just the interrupt latency alone, you must generate a lot of interrupts, one immediately after the other, so as to accumulate an easily measurable interval and generate a good average.  The only way I know of to do that is with a 'bad' driver that does not clear an interrupt so as to generate another interrupt upon interrupt return.